# Write function on Latex?

Tags: math-mode, errors

I tried to write this code in Latex but after the Exist symbol its all /em and together.

[image]

Comment: Show the code you use, and never ignore compilation errors.

Comment: $O(f(n))$ = {\exists\ positive constants $c$}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `\exists` is a math symbol, as I mentioned, don't ignore compilation errors. `$O(f(c)) = \{g(n) : \text{$\exist$s  positive constants $c$ and $n_0$ such that $\forall n \geq n_0$ we have $0\leq g(n) \geq cf(n)}\}`. I tend to write the entire condition part inside `\text` instead of jumping in and out.

Comment: Don’t use such long set descriptions that are difficult to parse. `$O(f)$ is the set of all functions $g$ such that, for some positive $c$ and $n_0$, it holds that $0\le g(n)\le cf(n)$, for all $n\ge n_0$.`

Comment: @daleif what about line breaks?

Answer (score 2):

The way to reproduce that image is

```
$O(f(n))=\{g(n):\exists$ \textbf{positive constants $c$ and $n_0$ 
such that $\forall n\ge n_0$ we have $0\le g(n)\le cf(n)\}$}.
```

Note that `\exists` is a math symbol, so it must be typed in math mode.

However set-builder notation with very long textual descriptions are very hard to parse, because typically the closing brace will be on a different line than the opening one. The long part in boldface is even worse.

If I were to write that sentence, I'd write

```
$O(f)$ is the set consisting of all functions $g$ for which there exist 
positive constants $c$ and $n_0$ such that, for all $n\ge n_0$, it holds 
that $0\le g(n)\le cf(n)$.
```

Pretend you're talking to an audience, so you cannot use `\exists` and `\forall`, but have to spell them.